# Dynamically Binded Dropdownlist always taking first value when get by ddl.SelectedValue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamically bind dropdownlist from which i want insert selected value in a table. But when I submit the form it is taking the very first value of dropdownlist not the selected value and inserts the first value of the dropdownlist.

Here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection.getConnection()))
    {
        string sqlGetClass = "select pk_classID,brachName+'-'+classYear as classInfo from tbl_studentClass";
        SqlCommand cmdGetClass = new SqlCommand(sqlGetClass, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdGetClass);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddlClass.DataSource = ds;
        ddlClass.DataTextField = "classInfo";
        ddlClass.DataValueField = "pk_classID";
        ddlClass.DataBind();
        ddlClass.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--SELECT--", ""));
        conn.Close();
    }
}

protected void btnStdRegisterSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dateOfBirth = txtStdDOBYear.Text+"-"+ddlStdDOBMonth.SelectedValue + "-"+txtStdDOBDate.Text;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection.getConnection()))
    {
        string sqlInsertStd = "Insert into tbl_studentRegistration (firstName,surname,studentUsername,studentPassword,studentDOB,studentGender,studentMobile,class) values(@firstName,@surname,@studentUsername,@studentPassword,@studentDOB,@studentGender,@studentMobile,@class)";
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdInsertStd = new SqlCommand(sqlInsertStd, conn);
        cmdInsertStd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtStdFirstName.Text);
        cmdInsertStd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", txtStdSurname.Text);
        cmdInsertStd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentUsername", txtStdUsername.Text);
        cmdInsertStd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentPassword", txtStdPassword.Text);
        cmdInsertStd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentDOB", DateTime.Parse(dateOfBirth).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        cmdInsertStd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentGender", ddlStdGender.SelectedValue.ToString());
        cmdInsertStd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentMobile", txtStdMobile.Text);
        cmdInsertStd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", ddlClass.SelectedValue);

        cmdInsertStd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        txtStdFirstName.Text = "";
        txtStdSurname.Text = "";
        txtStdUsername.Text = "";
        ddlClass.SelectedValue = "";
        txtStdPassword.Text = "";
        txtStdConfirmPassword.Text = "";
        ddlStdDOBMonth.SelectedValue = "";
        txtStdDOBDate.Text = "";
        txtStdDOBYear.Text = "";
        ddlStdGender.SelectedValue = "";
        txtStdMobile.Text = "";
        Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx");
    }
}
```

Please help I am new to asp.net

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are adding the items into `DropDownList` for every Page request as your code added in `Page_Load` EventHandler. so the `DropDownList` always contain the first item as selectedItem even though you selected different item.

**Solution:** You need to append the items into `DropDownList` only when page is Loaded but not on every PostBack request.

You can use `Page.IsPostBack` to identify wether page request is PostBack request or not.

Try This:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection.getConnection()))
    {
        string sqlGetClass = "select pk_classID,brachName+'-'+classYear as 
                                         classInfo from tbl_studentClass";
        SqlCommand cmdGetClass = new SqlCommand(sqlGetClass, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdGetClass);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddlClass.DataSource = ds;
        ddlClass.DataTextField = "classInfo";
        ddlClass.DataValueField = "pk_classID";
        ddlClass.DataBind();
        ddlClass.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--SELECT--", ""));
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load executes every time the page posts back, such as when you click your submit button. You should put your using stateme3nt in a

conditional:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection.getConnection()))
        {
            string sqlGetClass = "select pk_classID,brachName+'-'+classYear as classInfo from tbl_studentClass";
            SqlCommand cmdGetClass = new SqlCommand(sqlGetClass, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdGetClass);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            ddlClass.DataSource = ds;
            ddlClass.DataTextField = "classInfo";
            ddlClass.DataValueField = "pk_classID";
            ddlClass.DataBind();
            ddlClass.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--SELECT--", ""));
            conn.Close();
        }
      }
    }
```

So that your list is not repopulated every time you click your submiit button.
(you should consider putting the list population code in a separate method)